# Mongodb display nested reference object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the below Schema for mongodb (For my mean stack app).

```
var helpSchema = new Schema({
    //_id: Number,
    description: String,
    summary: String,
    flows: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Flow' }]
});


var flowSchema = new Schema({
    _problem: { type: Number, ref: 'Help' },
    name: String,
    steps: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Step' }]
});
```

I am inserting to the database as below:

```
var help = new models.Help();
        help.description = 'description';
        help.summary = 'summary';

        var flow = new models.Flow();
        flow.name = 'name';

        help.flows.push(flow);
 help.save(function(err) {
...
}
```

Value is inserted to db and i am able to query. 
**db.helps.find();** returns below result

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5786520f580cc96c31c90769"), "summary" : "summary", "description" : "description", "flows" : [ ObjectId("5786520f580cc96c31c9076a") ], "__v" : 0 }
```

Now can i query from command line and see the value within the object in flows array? I searched and found that in can query a field within nested object. But can i display this value in command line?

Comment: `db.flows.find({_id: <from help query>})`

Comment: Its gives me an empty result. Also if i ran show collections, it shows me only helps. Is that an issue?

Answer (score 1):

To request only the values of your field `flows` in an array, you can use [map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.map/).
It needs as input parameter :

> A function to apply to each document visited by the cursor.

This will give you :

```
flows_id = function(doc) { return doc.flows; }
db.helps.find().map(flows_id)
```

To extract value from `ObjectId` value, you need to call `valueOf` for each item :

```
flows_id = function(doc) {
    var array = [];
    doc.flows.forEach(function(myDoc){
        array.push(myDoc.valueOf());
    });
    return array;
}

db.helps.find().map(flows_id)
```

Comment: It gives me the object. But can i view the fields within the object?

Comment: do you mean the value inside `ObjectId` like that : `[ "5786520f580cc96c31c9076a","5786520f580cc96c31c9076b" ]` ?

Comment: yes.. query gives me  ObjectId("5786520f580cc96c31c9076a"). Can i get the value inside that object?

Comment: Thanks it helped. I found the actual reason as well. As i said in the comments above, the flow collection was not being created and only helps was present. This was the reason. I had forgot to specifically save flows collection. Thanks all for the help.

Comment: you're welcome, you can mark it as answered if you are satisfied with that